# How to make Google Chrome reopen my tabs after closing it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Let's say I have 4 tabs open, then I close the browser to shutdown my computer.

I'd like that next time I turn it back on and open the browser, the 4 tabs to be there. If they got saved onto some cache or they just reload again, I don't care.

I want it to always reopen all the tabs I have open at the time of closure, much like Notepad++. And much like a smartphone's browser, now that I think of it.

I am aware of Ctrl+Shift+T to reopen the last closed tab. It's not what I am looking for.

If that is not possible with Google Chrome, then: is there any other browser capable of that?

Comment: Yup! It does. I couldn't find that question before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings page "On Startup" tick "Continue where you left off"